# Mysql запрос

Tags: запрос, mysql

есть две таблицы: table1 (id, name); table2 (id, id_t1, date, status).
Как написать условие для вывода записей, у которых table1.id=table2.id_t1, status=0 и дата наибольшая (table2.date)?
Т.е. для каждой записи из 1 таблицы смотреть последнюю дату во второй таблице и, если статус равен нулю - выводить. 
Пробовал max(), но тогда оно одну запись выводит..

Comment: > Пробовал max(), но тогда оно одну запись выводит..

Потому, что групперовка (*group by*) нужна по id_t1 во второй таблице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы вот так написал:

```
select table1.id, table1.name, a.max_date
from
    (select id_t1, MAX(date) as max_date 
    from table2
    where status = 0 
    group by id_t1) a
join
    table1
on a.id_t1 = table1.id
```

Comment: почти, но оно выводит записи, где status=0 и дата наибольшая, а нужно смотреть только по последней дате для каждой записи из table1 и выводить, если status=0

Comment: Это как?

      select table1.id, table1.name, a.max_date
      from (select id_t1, MAX(date) as max_date, status 
      from table2 group by id_t1) a join table1
        on a.id_t1 = table1.id where a.status = 0

Comment: выводит последние даты даже если их status не равен нулю

Comment: @rej ну такое возможно, если в table2 есть две записи с максимальной датой и разным status (или дата не максимальная среди всех, но максимум по status=0).

Кстати, то, что написал я, с точки зрения нормального sql -- неправильно, но для mysql должно работать. А вообще, нельзя ли привести пример данных, где идёт бяка?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

    INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (10, 'Андрей'),
    (9, 'Виктор'),
    (8, 'Федор'),
    (7, 'Иван');

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `date` date NOT NULL,
      `id_t1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `status` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
    
    INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `date`, `id_t1`, `status`) VALUES
    (2, '2014-01-06', 7, 0),
    (3, '2014-01-01', 8, 0),
    (4, '2014-01-05', 9, 0),
    (5, '2014-01-04', 10, 0),
    (6, '2014-01-03', 8, 1);

Comment: @rej ага. Тогда может так?

    select table1.id, table1.name, table2.date 
    from
      (select id_t1, MAX(date) as max_date
      from table2 group by id_t1) a join table1
      on a.id_t1 = table1.id join table2 on a.id_t1 = table2.id_t1
      and a.max_date = table2.date
    where table2.status = 0

Ну для table1 и table2 лучше задать алиасы. Результат

    |  7 | Иван         | 2014-01-06 |
    |  9 | Виктор       | 2014-01-05 |
    | 10 | Андрей       | 2014-01-04 |

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.id,
       t.name,
       (select max(a.date) from table2 a where a.id_t1 = t.id and a.status = 0) as max_date
  from table1 t
```

Comment: ваш запрос выводит записи с максимальной датой из тех, что со статусом 0
10 Андрей 2014-01-04
9 Виктор 2014-01-05
8 Федор 2014-01-01
7 Иван 2014-01-06

Comment: Тогда я не понял что Вам нужно. Можете объяснить более развернуто?

Comment: нужно выбрать максимальную дату для каждой записи из 1й таблицы, и, если статус 0 - вывести

Comment: а как в ваш запрос добавить вывод поля status? если убрать and a.status = 0, потом на пхп уже отсортировать можно

Comment: @Autocrab группировка по id (id_t1) нужна